# Mysql select query working but giving error on update query

Tags: mysql, join, left-join, crud, outer-join

I have a select query which is working fine.

```
select t1.HOST, t1.portalId from table1 t1, table2 t2
where SUBSTRING_INDEX(t1.HOST, '.',1)= SUBSTRING_INDEX(t2.HOST, '.', 1)
```

However, a similar update query is giving an error

```
update table1  set table1.portalId = table2.portalId,
where SUBSTRING_INDEX(table1.HOST, '.',1)= SUBSTRING_INDEX(table2.HOST, '.', 1)
```

`Getting error: "Unknown Column table1.HOST in where clause"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use:

```
update table1
JOIN table2 
  ON SUBSTRING_INDEX(table1.HOST, '.',1)= SUBSTRING_INDEX(table2.HOST, '.', 1)
set table1.portalId = table2.portalId
-- WHERE ...
```

Comment: I am trying it with `limit` but it is not working. `update table1
JOIN table2 
  ON SUBSTRING_INDEX(table1.HOST, '.',1)= SUBSTRING_INDEX(table2.HOST, '.', 1)
set table1.portalId = table2.portalId
limit 2;`  Error: `MySQL Error: Incorrect usage of UPDATE and LIMIT`

Comment: @meallhour In your original query there is no `limit`. Please avoid XY question and post your real query (if possible prepare demo http://dbfiddle.uk)